# Complex PHP/Perl regular expression for emoticons

Tags: php, regex, perl

I've checked google for help on this subject but all the answers keep overlooking a fatal flaw in the replacement method.

Essentially I have a set of emoticons such as :) LocK :eek and so on and need to replace them with image tags. The problem I'm having is identifying that a particular emoticon is not part of a word and is alone on a line. For example on our site we allow 'quick links' which are not included in the smiley replacement which take the format go:forum, user:Username and so on. Pretty much all answers I've read don't allow for this possiblity and as such break these links (i.e. go<img src="image.gif" />orum). I've tried experimenting around with different ways to get around this to check for the start of the line, spaces/newline characters and so on but I've not had much luck.

Any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated. Oh also I'm using PHP 5 and the preg_% functions.

Thanks,
Rupert S.

*Edit 18/04/2011:*

Thanks for your help peeps :) Have created the final regex that I though I'd share with everyone, had a couple problems to do with special space chars including newline but it's now working like a dream the final regex is:

(?<=\s|\A|\n|\r|\t|\v|\<br \/\>|\<br\>)(:S)(?=\s|\Z|$|\n|\r|\t|\v|\<br \/\>|\<br\>)

Comment: Use word boundaries around your pattern?

Comment: I've tried using that but I'm not sure if I've used it right as you get word boundaries and not-word boundaries and I don't understand what is meant by that? are spaces and stuff not-words?

Comment: Assert that the emoticons are surrounded by spaces `(?<=\s)[<:-}]+(?=\s)` - that should cover what you want, and is more concrete than word/non-word boundaries.

Comment: Will that include characters/entities such as start of line/end of line/new line and so on? for example if the smilie is at the end of a line it would not be surrounded by spaces on one side?

Comment: `\s` means any whitespace, including linebreaks. It would fail at the very end of the subject (if no trailing newline exists). For such cases use `(?=\s|$)`

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you, this has fixed my prob :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To complete the comment into an answer: The simplest workaround would be to assert that the emoticons are always surrounded by whitespace.

```
 (?<=\s|^)[<:-}]+(?=\s|$)
```

The `\s` covers normal spaces and line breaks. Just to be safe `^` and `$` cover occurrences at the start or very end of the text subject. The assertions themselves do not match, so can be ignored in the replacement string/callback.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do all the replace in one single preg_replace, try this:

```
preg_replace('/(?<=^|\s)(:\)|:eek)(?=$|\s)/e'
    ,"'$1'==':)'?'<img src=\"smile.gif\"/>':('$1'==':eek'?'<img src=\"eek.gif\"/>':'$1')"
    ,$input);
```